# J1 visa - Confusion in how to apply

Tags: usa, visa, indian-citizens, india, internship

I am a freelancer ( web dev ) and a student from India. The company I work for ( in USA ), asked me for a internship. The company is a bit small ( Don't know much about visa ). I researched in google, that I need j1 visa to travel to USA for that internship. But I don't know any sponsor or even don't know where do I find them.

I have questions like:

> What should the company?
>   What should I do?
>   Who are the sponsor and host?

I am having no guide in this. Can anyone guide me on this? Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Are you a college/university student (or recent graduate) interested in the Exchange Visitor Program under the J-1 visa, or are you an employee of a US company which wants to bring you to the US for training/internship?

Comment: @Dorothy Thanks for your response. I am still studying. Graduating in 2018. And I need J-1 visa for the internship in that company. I just work for them from home ( freelancing ), not a full time employee. It's just 2 month program, so I could utilize my summer holidays for that internship.

Comment: That's not what the J-1 is for. Review this [Fact Sheet](https://j1visa.state.gov/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/FactSheet_J1Visa.pdf) and you'll see that a company which currently employs you is not a J1 sponsor. Here are the [Sponsoring Organizations](https://j1visa.state.gov/participants/how-to-apply/sponsor-search/?program=Intern)

Comment: @Dorothy Oh, but it reads intern: `college and university`?? So I am not eligible for J1 visa? Or what else I am eligible for?

Comment: The problem is that you are already employed by a US company, and getting paid by it, right? The J1 is an _exchange_ program and an internship would have to at an approved program. If your current employer wants you in the US for an internship (paid or unpaid), then it would most likely require a [work visa](https://travel.state.gov/content/visas/en/employment.html)

Comment: Since you say the US company which employs you part time asked you to intern for it in the US, review this information on [US work visas](http://www.ustraveldocs.com/in/in-niv-typework.asp) for temporary, non-immigrant purposes.

Comment: @Dorothy Okay thank you so much for you help. Can student get work visa?? And also I need to find sponsor for that? I don't know what's the solution for this. They just hired me for hourly based work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47540/discussion-between-dorothy-and-hemnath-mouli).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As we discussed in chat, you are a university student who does part time work for a US employer. Should that employer wish to bring you to the US to work for it for a short period, paid or unpaid, you would need a work visa and the company would need to file a petition for a non-immigrant worker on your behalf. As you realized, this is not quite the right fit for undergraduates, nor would it be a good idea to try to obtain a J-1 visa just to enter the US and work at your part-time employer.

Better, I would encourage you to continue to explore the J-1 Exchange Visitor Program (EVP) independent of any connection with that company.

[The Exchange Visitor (J) non-immigrant visa category](https://j1visa.state.gov/basics/) is for individuals approved to participate in work-and study-based exchange visitor programs.

> The EVP provides opportunities for around 300,000 foreign visitors per year to experience United States (U.S.) society and culture and engage with Americans. There are fifteen different categories under the J-1 visa program, of which, thirteen categories include privately-funded programs that are implemented under the auspices of the Office of Private Sector Exchange in the Department’s Bureau of Educational and Cultural Affairs. The Department designates more than 1,400 for-profit, non-profit, or federal, state, and local government entities to conduct such private sector programs.
>
> Exchange visitors on private sector programs may study, teach, do research, share their specialized skills, or receive on-the-job training for periods ranging from a few weeks to several years. In addition to the thirteen private sector exchange categories listed below, the J-1 visa program also includes two categories that are publicly funded: International Visitors and Government Visitors.
>
> [**Who Comes on the EVP**](https://j1visa.state.gov/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/FactSheet_J1Visa.pdf)?
>
> EVP participants are young leaders and entrepreneurs, students, fledgling and more seasoned professionals eager to hone their skills, strengthen their English language abilities, connect with Americans, and learn more about the U.S.

EVP requires sponsorship and the [Designated Sponsors](https://j1visa.state.gov/participants/how-to-apply/sponsor-search/) are organizations throughout the US. Many sponsors can place participants anywhere in the United States, regardless of their official location.